# JSON query filter transport

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

I'd like to transfer from client to server WHERE clause as JSON.
I have created `FilterInfo.class` and `Filter.class` on the server:

```
   public class Filter<T> {
      private String fieldName;
      private String operand;
      private T value; 
   }

   public class FilterInfo {
     private List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();
     private String orderBy;
   }
```

Example of my `filterInfo` as JSON:

```
{
  "filters": [
    { "fieldName" : "Name",
      "operand" : "=",
      "value" : "John" },

    { "fieldName" : "Age",
      "operand"  : ">=",
      "value"  : "30" }

  ],
  "orderBy": "Age"
}
```

Then it should be great to read this JSON on server and build query.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .setDateFormat(Constants.MY_DATE_FORMAT)
                .create();
FilterInfo filterInfo = gson.fromJson(jsonString, FilterInfo.class);
```

Unfortunately, `Date` and `Integer` values deserialize as `String` and `Double`.

I have seen examples with `TypeToken`, custom serializers/deserializers but cannot guess how to apply them to me.

I would happy if you figure out my mistakes, and suggest good idea.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, Date and Integer values deserialize as String and Double.

When you define a generic type field like `Field<T>` -- Gson cannot have enough information on how a certain value should be deserialized to a certain type. It's a fundamental limitation: there is just no type information. Therefore Gson resolves `<T>` as if it were parameterized as `<Object>`. When a certain target "slot" (list element, object field, etc) is considered `java.lang.Object`, Gson resolves a JSON value according to the type of the value literal: if it's something like `"..."`, then it's probably a `String`; if it's something like `0`, then it's definitely a `Number` and more accurate: `Double` (doubles are the biggest standard numeric values -- Gson just saves time on numbers type detection and parsing + the user code should have had `java.util.List<Number>` and detect a particular list element with `instanceof` -- it might be an integer, a long or a double value -- not very conventient to use, so `java.lang.Double` is the default strategy). So that you have strings and doubles instead of dates and integers: Gson simple *cannot have your desired type information itself*.

Why you cannot use type tokens directly: type tokens are used to specify type parameters for elements of *the same type*, so you cannot have multiple type tokens to cover different types even for a two-element list (list types tokens define a type for all list elements).

To accomplish what you need you can create a type adapter and a respective type adapter factory to perform some kind of lookup to resolve the concrete type. Say,

```java
final class FilterTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // This is a strategy up to your needs: resolve a java.lang.reflect.Type by a filter object content 
    private final Function<? super JsonObject, ? extends Type> typeResolvingStrategy;

    private FilterTypeAdapterFactory(final Function<? super JsonObject, ? extends Type> typeResolvingStrategy) {
        this.typeResolvingStrategy = typeResolvingStrategy;
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getFilterTypeAdapterFactory(final Function<? super JsonObject, ? extends Type> typeResolvingStrategy) {
        return new FilterTypeAdapterFactory(typeResolvingStrategy);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // Is it the Filter class?
        if ( Filter.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            // Get the JsonObject type adapter
            final TypeAdapter<JsonObject> jsonObjectTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonObject.class);
            // This is a function to resolve a downstream type adapter by the given type
            // If a downstream parser is not used, then the lookup will end up with self-recursion...
            final Function<Type, TypeAdapter<T>> typeTypeAdapterFunction = type -> {
                // Create a type token dynamically
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final TypeToken<T> delegateTypeToken = (TypeToken<T>) TypeToken.get(type);
                // And get the downstream type adapter
                return gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, delegateTypeToken);
            };
            return new FilterTypeAdapter<>(jsonObjectTypeAdapter, typeTypeAdapterFunction, typeResolvingStrategy);
        }
        // Not a thing we can handle? Return null, and Gson will try to perform lookup itself
        return null;
    }

    private static final class FilterTypeAdapter<T>
            extends TypeAdapter<T> {

        private final TypeAdapter<JsonObject> jsonObjectTypeAdapter;
        private final Function<? super Type, ? extends TypeAdapter<T>> typeAdapterResolver;
        private final Function<? super JsonObject, ? extends Type> typeResolvingStrategy;

        private FilterTypeAdapter(
                final TypeAdapter<JsonObject> jsonObjectTypeAdapter,
                final Function<? super Type, ? extends TypeAdapter<T>> typeAdapterResolver,
                final Function<? super JsonObject, ? extends Type> typeResolvingStrategy
        ) {
            this.jsonObjectTypeAdapter = jsonObjectTypeAdapter;
            this.typeAdapterResolver = typeAdapterResolver;
            this.typeResolvingStrategy = typeResolvingStrategy;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) {
            // If you ever need it, then you have to implement it
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public T read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            // Read the next {...} and convert it to JsonObject
            final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonObjectTypeAdapter.read(in);
            // Now resolve a real type by the given JsonObject instance
            // ... and resolve its type adapter
            final TypeAdapter<T> delegateTypeAdapter = typeAdapterResolver.apply(typeResolvingStrategy.apply(jsonObject));
            // Since the reader has the {...} value already consumed, we cannot read it at this moment
            // But we can convert the cached JsonObject to the target type object
            return delegateTypeAdapter.fromJsonTree(jsonObject);
        }

    }

}
```

Ok, how it can be used? I have tested it with the following mappings:

```java
final class Filter<T> {

    final String fieldName = null;
    final String operand = null;
    final T value = null;

}
```

```java
final class FilterInfo {

    final List<Filter<?>> filters = null;
    final String orderBy = null;

}
```

## In-JSON type names strategy

If you can supply type names in your JSON to lookup the filter type, then a sample JSON might be look like:

```
{
    "filters": [
        {"_type": "date", "fieldName": "fooDate", "operand": "=", "value": "1997-12-20"},
        {"_type": "int", "fieldName": "barInteger", "operand": ">=", "value": 10}
    ],
    "orderBy": "fooDate"
}
```

Now the `Gson` instance could be built like this:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getFilterTypeAdapterFactory(jsonObject -> {
            if ( !jsonObject.has("_type") ) {
                return defaultFilterType;
            }
            switch ( jsonObject.get("_type").getAsString() ) {
            case "int":
                return integerFilterType;
            case "date":
                return dateFilterType;
            default:
                return defaultFilterType;
            }
        }))
        .create();
```

## Alternative strategy

If you don't want to enhance your JSON documents (at that's good), then you can just replace the strategy, however resolving types can be more complicated due to several reasons since it strongly depends on the given filter value names (the same name might be used for different types):

```
{
    "filters": [
        {"fieldName": "fooDate", "operand": "=", "value": "1997-12-20"},
        {"fieldName": "barInteger", "operand": ">=", "value": 10}
    ],
    "orderBy": "fooDate"
}
```

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getFilterTypeAdapterFactory(jsonObject -> {
            if ( !jsonObject.has("fieldName") ) {
                return defaultFilterType;
            }
            switch ( jsonObject.get("fieldName").getAsString() ) {
            case "barInteger":
                return integerFilterType;
            case "fooDate":
                return dateFilterType;
            default:
                return defaultFilterType;
            }
        }))
        .create();
```

Note that `TypeToken`s and `Type`s can be considered immutable and constant, so they can be put in a separate class:

```java
final class Types {

    private Types() {
    }

    static final Type defaultFilterType = new TypeToken<Filter<Object>>() {
    }.getType();

    static final Type integerFilterType = new TypeToken<Filter<Integer>>() {
    }.getType();

    static final Type dateFilterType = new TypeToken<Filter<Date>>() {
    }.getType();

}
```

Now, for both stragies, the following code

```java
final FilterInfo filterInfo = gson.fromJson(JSON, FilterInfo.class);
System.out.println(filterInfo.orderBy);
for ( final Filter filter : filterInfo.filters ) {
    System.out.println(filter.fieldName + filter.operand + filter.value + " of " + filter.value.getClass());
}
```

will output:

> fooDate
>   fooDate=Sat Dec 20 00:00:00 EET 1997 of class java.util.Date
>   barInteger>=10 of class java.lang.Integer

Comment: But...  Could you kindly help me refactor lambda function to Java 6. 
I began like this... and cannot complete.
`Function<? super Type, ? extends TypeAdapter<T>> typeTypeAdapterFunction = new Function<Type, TypeAdapter<T>>() {
                @Override
                public TypeAdapter<T> apply(Type input) {
                    return null; //  
                }
            };`
Thanks a lot!

Comment: To backport lamdas to java 6, just write an anonymous inner class: `new FilterTypeAdapterFactory() {...}`. Then, you won't have the `getFilterTypeAdapterFactory` method anymore. You can create `FilterTypeAdapterFactory` local variables instead.

Comment: @AzamatAlmukhametov The body of the anonymous function is `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final TypeToken<T> delegateTypeToken = (TypeToken<T>) TypeToken.get(type); return gson.getDelegateAdapter(FilterTypeAdapterFactory.this, delegateTypeToken);` (note `FilterTypeAdapterFactory.this` -- you can "capture" the enclosing class `this`, whilst lambdas allow omit this syntax; if using `this` in the anonymous class, then `this` points to the anonymous class as usually).

Comment: @TamasRev Exposing constructors is usually a not that good idea. Leaving the `getFilterTypeAdapterFactory` method would allow to return a single instance cached in a private static field (not letting a caller know how to instantiate `FilterTypeAdapterFactory` -- let it never bother of it) + that static factory returns `TypeAdapterFactory` that's an interface and you can even wrap the real instance in a decorator or whatever like that so the caller won't even know it (additionally, the type adapter factory does not extend the interface, so the interface is enough). + Let IoC be there.

Comment: Dear, @LyubomyrShaydariv.
There is another one Lambda expression which my brain isnt responsible to backport to java 6 - is `GsonBuilder....`. Oh, please, could you help.

Comment: @AzamatAlmukhametov Come on, this is easy! `getFilterTypeAdapterFactory` is declared to accept a function that converts `com.google.gson.JsonObject` to `java.lang.reflect.Type`. Knowing that you can re-write the lambda function as `new Function<JsonObject, Type>() { @Override public Type apply(final JsonObject jsonObject) { ... } }`, where `...` is a placeholder for any your code.

Comment: Dear, @LyubomyrShaydariv, thank a lot. You know, actually in my situation I'm not ready to to fully understand this TypeAdapterFactory. So, at that time I decided to implement custom code to convert object which has deserialized  by standard Gson adapter... In the future I hope to deeper learn Gson framework... Thanks!

Comment: @AzamatAlmukhametov I am glad I could help you out, you are welcome!